# Lose data with django-south schemamigration

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have a django model with around 500k entries in mysql database. I'd like to add another field to my model:

```
site = models.ForeignKey(Site, verbose_name=_('Site'),null=True,blank=True).
```

But I lose all the data, by running:

```
python manage.py schemamigration product --auto
python manage.py migrate product
```

The migration script generated is:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding field 'Product.site'
        db.add_column('product_product', 'site',
                      self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(to=orm['sites.Site'], null=True, blank=True),
                      keep_default=False)
    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting field 'Product.site'
        db.delete_column('product_product', 'site_id')
```

The sql generated for migration is:

```
Running migrations for product:
 - Migrating forwards to 0016_auto__add_field_product_site.
 > product:0016_auto__add_field_product_site
   = SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; []
   = ALTER TABLE `product_product` ADD COLUMN `site_id` integer NULL; []
   - no dry run output for alter_column() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   = ALTER TABLE `product_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `site_id_refs_id_10570b8a766fecf5` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `django_site` (`id`); []
   = CREATE INDEX `product_product_6223029` ON `product_product` (`site_id`); []
```

The latest migration history from 'python manager.py migrate product--list' is:

```
(*) 0011_auto__add_field_product_category_str
(*) 0012_auto__add_field_product_store_id
(*) 0013_auto__del_field_product_site__del_unique_product_sku_site__del_unique_
(*) 0014_auto__chg_field_product_short_description__chg_field_product_descripti
(*) 0015_auto__add_field_product_phase_tag
( ) 0016_auto__add_field_product_site
```

Fortunately, I have the database backup. Is there a way to add a field to the model without losing the existing data?

Comment: have you tried writing the migration manually, instead of using the `--auto` option?

Comment: Could be better to show the content of generated migration and corresponding executed SQLs...

Comment: Show us the migration generated for the product app, as well as your output of ./manage.py migrate --list

Comment: @okm the scripts are now added, I don't see command responsible for deleting the data

Comment: @stevejalim the latest migration history is added, thanks for asking

Comment: @JeffTratner Not yet, I only follows the south tutorial so far. Is it better to write the migration manually?

Comment: This should work fine without any deleting unless you have some sql trigger that will do that. Also, are you sure that the data actually get deleted after running this migration? Did you checked it in the database?

Comment: What DB engine? MySQL?

Comment: @Aldarund I check the data through product.objects.count(), I didn't check it through sql. How can I check the existence of any sql trigger?

Comment: @Aldarund yes, it's mysql on AWS's RDS.

Comment: You should check data via sql. And you can check trigger using SHOW TRIGGERS; - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-triggers.html

Answer (score 0):

With 500k records, this might not be possible for your situation, but for the benefit of others who might be coming to this page, you might want to try using django-evolution https://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/ instead of South.  I have used both and have found that while it is less full-featured, Evolution handles most migrations with far less fuss than South.